# Least computationally expensive bitwise addition

Tags: efficiency, arithmetic, bit-manipulation

I am familiar with the oft-cited method of bitwise addition using XOR and left shift for the carry, applied recursively. I was wondering if this is the least computationally expensive way to achieve simple addition modulo 2^n using bitwise operators.

Comment: It depends how you define "computationally expensive." Number of gates, gate delay

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)